# Converting an EXE file to XML

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6

I have an executable package (.exe) of an application. How do convert this executable to an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) package?

I am aware of converting a .msi into .wxs using the following.

```
dark.exe installer.msi
```

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered in this general form. That  would require us to consider things like hand-written installers, which surely can't be automatically converted into a proper MSI database? MSI also has some limitations (like limited GUI options, and not being able to install a second MSI as part of the installation) which don't apply to an exe. Therefore, it's important to know how the exe was generated.

Comment: Yes, in general converting a setup is more like creating a setup from scratch. There's no common recipe.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great little mini-tutorial.  It's probably all you need:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with

1) Create Wix XML file

```
EXAMPLE:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
</Wix>
```

2) Build an MSI for your .exe

```
EXAMPLE:
candle example.wxs
light example.wixobj
```

3) Voila.  If there's nothing more complicated than "install the .exe", you're done!
   Take the .msi to a difference PC and test.

The above link also discusses other scenarios, if you need them.  For example:

```
ANOTHER, MORE REALISTIC .WIX FILE:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="12345678-1234-1234-1234-111111111111" 
            Name="Example Product Name" Version="0.0.1" Manufacturer="Example Company Name" Language="1033">
      <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Comments="Windows Installer Package"/>
      <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
         <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Example">
               <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-222222222222">
                  <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="example.exe"/>
               </Component>
            </Directory>
         </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
         <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles"/>
      </Feature>
   </Product>
</Wix>
```

Here is the "standard" tutorial, with much other information:

- http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/

Bon soir (at least here in California ;))

'Hope that helps!

Comment: :thanks for the help i am aware of how to start with creating .msi however i woud be more interested to know if i have an .exe for an application that i want to decode into a useful readable source doe format like c++ , or something related to that , that would help

Answer (score 1):

Use [UniExtract](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) to extract the MSIs from the EXE, then apply dark on the MSIs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11999818)

Comment: @pczeus That's the download page for UniExtract. What exactly should I include?